# Prepend image not showing up in IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer

I'm using this:

```
jQuery(".srOrderTR").prepend("<div style='float: left; position: absolute;'><img src='/v/vspfiles/images/manageResultsText.png'></div>");
```

Working in every browser except IE. Seems stupidly straight forward.. any ideas?

Comment: which IE version are you using?

Comment: What's the point of floating an absolutely positioned element? As well, unless you've got a parent element somewhere with `position: relative`, you're positioning that div absolutely relative to the top-left corner of the document.

Comment: Try this post, maybe of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730974/jquery-prepend-working-in-all-borwsers-except-ie7

Comment: I'm using IE8. I have this image exactly positioned where I want it. Yeah I don't need to float it left, I forgot to delete that code out.

Comment: I even took off the DIV and it's not prepending. It is loading, just not being shown.